# subtract multiple dates within one id

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datediff

I'm trying to accomplish something in mySQL, which is difficult due to the lack of a "lag" function and because of all the examples I've read regarding date differences, since in all those examples there's always one ID to one date. In here, I am trying to do the date differences within an ID, and when the date difference is over 60, then returning an indicator of 1, else 0.

Not sure what the best way is to go about this. Would it be some combination of using row_number() with the date? The snag is doing this within multiple IDs, as a lot of things I read don't cover that. Any direction would be helpful.
Thanks!

```
ID  |   Service Date    |   Date Difference |   Indicator
1   |   1/22/2016       |   0               |   1
1   |   3/26/2016       |   64              |   1
1   |   5/25/2016       |   60              |   0
1   |   9/15/2016       |   113             |   1
2   |   8/1/2016        |   0               |   1
3   |   1/26/2016       |   0               |   1
3   |   3/9/2016        |   43              |   0
3   |   4/30/2016       |   52              |   0
4   |   8/9/2016        |   0               |   1
5   |   11/19/2016      |   0               |   1
6   |   10/14/2016      |   0               |   1
7   |   1/31/2016       |   0               |   1
7   |   8/11/2016       |   193             |   1
```

Comment: You can't use row number with mysql either.

Comment: Use a user variable to hold the date from the previous row, and then use `DATEDIFF(service_date, @previous_date)` to get the difference.

Comment: You also need a variable for the previous ID. When the ID changes, you start over.

Comment: Having rows be interdependent like that is a bit of a smell. Is there something else they're categorized by, e.g. a user id? Perhaps you could try storing a reference/foreign key (on self) to the previous service for that row.

Answer (score 1):

```
create view id_and_date as 
select id, service_date from your table;

create view id_and_date_and_prior as 
select 
a.id, a.service_date, 
coalesce(
  (select max(b.service_date) from id_and_date b 
    where b.id = a.id and b.service_date < a.service_date), 
 a.service_date)
as prior_date
from id_and_date a

select a.id, a.service_date, a.prior_date
date_diff(a.service_date, a.prior_date) as diff, 
case when date_diff(a.service_date, a.prior_date) > 60 
  then 1 else 0 end 
as indicator
from id_and_date_and_prior a
```

Comment: The OP wants a rolling difference, not difference from first.

Comment: It will confuse me less, and educate me more, if you add your own answer (optionally pointing out the simplification)! If you want to reduce the number of views, I purposely separated them out to make it easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables, but this is tricky.  For this to work reliably, all the variables need to be assigned in a single expression:

```
select t.*, datediff(prev_date, date) as diff,
       (case when datediff(prev_date, date) < 60 then 0 else 1 end) as indicator
from (select t.*,
             (case when @id = id
                   then (case when (@prev := @d) = NULL then 'never' -- intentional
                              when (@d := date) = NULL then 'never' -- intentional
                              else @prev
                         end)
                   when (@d := date) = NULL then 'never' -- intentional
                   else NULL
              end) as prev_date
      from t cross join
           (select @id := -1, @d := '') params
      order by id, date
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting to simplify and correct the function calls from the answer provided by @tpdi. Please accept/upvote their answer, as this was pretty much copied from it.

Changes:

- date_diff to DATEDIFF
- removed create view calls in favor of subquery of `t`
- assigned variable to the diff value
- indicator of 0 on initial value as 0 diff to 1
- replaced when case in favor of IF

```
SELECT 
c.id, 
c.service_date, 
@diff := DATEDIFF(c.service_date, c.prior_date) AS diff, 
IF(@diff = 0 || @diff > 60, 1, 0) AS indicator
FROM (
    SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.service_date, 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT MAX(b.service_date) 
        FROM t AS b 
        WHERE b.id = a.id 
        AND b.service_date < a.service_date),
        a.service_date
    ) AS prior_date
    FROM t AS a
) AS c;
```

Will result in:

```
| id | service_date | diff | indicator |
| 1  | 2016-01-22   | 0    | 1         |
| 1  | 2016-03-26   | 64   | 1         |
| 1  | 2016-05-25   | 60   | 0         |
| 1  | 2016-09-15   | 113  | 1         |
| 2  | 2016-08-01   | 0    | 1         |
| 3  | 2016-01-26   | 0    | 1         |
| 3  | 2016-03-09   | 43   | 0         |
| 3  | 2016-04-30   | 52   | 0         |
| 4  | 2016-08-09   | 0    | 1         |
| 5  | 2016-11-19   | 0    | 1         |
| 6  | 2016-10-14   | 0    | 1         |
| 7  | 2016-01-31   | 0    | 1         |
| 7  | 2016-08-11   | 193  | 1         |
```

Comment: Nicely done. Afraid I haven't been doing Mysql lately, so the variable in the select is new to me! Thanks!

Comment: @tpdi thanks, I liked your use of `MAX` and `COALESCE`, the answer I was writing was using a `JOIN` in a similar way, but decided yours was a better approach.